# Show conditional thumbnail size in wooccommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, thumbnails

In WooCommerce prior to version 3.3 this code was working properly:

```
add_image_size( 'preview', $width = 3072, $height =3072, $crop = false ); 

$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
$filemeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $post_thumbnail_id, FALSE );

if ($filemeta['width']>3071 || $filemeta['height']>3071){
    $thumbnail_size    = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_large_size', 'preview' );
}else{
    $thumbnail_size    = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_large_size', 'large' );
}
```

This code was added to show the visitor a preview of the image at a reasonable size without using the original, full-size image. The thumbnails are shown with a watermark (not at this moment but that's another thing).

WooCommerce has, like said, changed the way the thumbnails are handled and the code is not working anymore. How can I get it working again in the most recent version of Woo?

To be complete: [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529579/how-to-show-conditional-image-thumbnail-size-in-woocommerce).

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT 2018-06-27**

As it turns out, WooCommerce has changed the product-image.php complete in version 3.3. I really don't know how to achieve what I want. In short is that: I don't want to use the full size image on my single product page or in the lightbox. The code above was working with a former version of WC. 
There was a thumbnail added (max 3072 x 3072 px.) called 'preview'. The code tested if this thumbnail exists and if so, used it. When the thumb 'preview' did not exists it uses the default 'large' thumbnail size.
How can I get it to work in the 3.3 and newer version.... I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_image_size( 'preview', 3072, 3072, false ); 

$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
$filemeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $post_thumbnail_id, FALSE );

function callbackFunc(){

  //set logic

  if (true){

    //do whatever you want

   }

}

apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_large_size', 'callbackFunc' );
```

Comment: sadly this is not working. As it turns out WC has reworked the product-image.php file in a way that my code (and therefor yours) will not fire. Any ideas left?