# Load same aspect ratio thumbnails in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, thumbnails, aspect-ratio, responsive-images

I've registered the size for a landscape image with a specific aspect ratio in WordPress (2048 pixels by 684 pixels);

```
add_image_size( '2048x684-header', 2048, 684, true); //crop.
```

I've set the ACF image field to return an Image ID and I'm calling the image using;

```
wp_get_attachment_image( $image, '2048x684-header' );
```

Let's say the aspect ratio is;
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

The function only generates a thumbnail if the original is ≥ 2048 pixels which means if the dimensions are less than 2048, the next thumbnai size is used in place which is not proportional to the desired aspect ratio. In my case a 1170x684 thumbnail is used i.e

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I'm looking for a way to generate more than one thumbnail for that specific aspect ratio i.e if the original image I'm uploading is smaller than 2024 wide, it will generate a proportional image with smaller dimensions but the same aspect ratio such as 1600 pixels x 534 pixels.

I have tried adding different sizes with the same aspect ratio such as;

```
add_image_size( '1600x534-header', 1600, 534, true); //crop. Smaller but same aspect ratio.
add_image_size( '1100x367-header', 1100, 367, true); //crop. Smaller but same aspect ratio.
```

This doesn't work as a fallback. Is there a way to set an image fallback i.e if the larger thumbnail is unavailable then use the next one specified?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my problem;  [How to show conditional image thumbnail size in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529579/how-to-show-conditional-image-thumbnail-size-in-woocommerce)

With these three image sizes that have the same aspect ratio;

```
add_image_size( '2048x684-header', 2048, 684, true); //crop. 
add_image_size( '1600x534-header', 1600, 534, true); //crop. Smaller proportion to the above.
add_image_size( '1100x367-header', 1100, 367, true); //crop. Smaller proportion to the above.
```

I was able to tweak the solution above;

```
   <?php 

    $filemeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $image, FALSE );

    if ( $filemeta['width']>2048 && $filemeta['height']>684 ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $headerImage, '2048x684-header' );
    } elseif ( $filemeta['width']>1600 && $filemeta['height']>534 ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $headerImage, '1600x534-header' );
    } elseif ( $filemeta['width']>1100 && $filemeta['height']>367 ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $headerImage, '1100x367-header' );
    } else ( $filemeta['width']>1100 && $filemeta['height']>367 ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $headerImage );
    }
    
    ?>
```